# Apache: redirect if host doesn't start with www or cdn

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My goal is to redirect to domain with `www.` if **both** these conditions are met:

1. current host is not www.example.com
2. current host is not cdn.example.com

I'm using a .htaccess file with this code, but the second condition is not honoured:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^cdn\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this did the trick:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(cdn|www)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I already tried it before but was tricked --by a cached redirect-- to think it was not working.

Comment: Can you give an example of a URL that did not work before but now works?  Like you want `abc.example.com` to rewrite as `www.example.com/abc` correct?  And this works correctly now?

Comment: @NeilNeyman `cdn.example.com` was redirected to `www.example.com`

Comment: Ok I misinterpreted that rule, sorry. They mean when using 'not' in the rewriterule, not when using it in the condition